# What becomes a coalition after winning a war against it?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

After acumulating too many agressive expension %, I had a coalition against me. There was 7 countries in this coalition. Fortunately, I won the war and it has been dissolved after the peace treaty.

**Does someone know what happening to all this countries who are angry about  aggresssive expension ?** Are they likely to start a second coalition against me soon ? Or it's impossible for them to create a new one for a certain amount of time ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They cannot join a coalition as long as the truce is in effect.

Once the truce ends and your AE is still high enough, they will immediately join a coalition again.